# nvim workflow with git

Tags: git, vim, config, neovim

I've been using nvim (lunarVim) for my private projects (mainly python) previously and it was convenient.

Since I was hired I have to collaborate in git and it became very difficult.

Could you recommend me some plugins of configs for the following purposes (or maybe tell about your workflow in general if you achieved that ideal IDE nvim level):

1. Efficiently view the history of a branch
2. Easily compare 2 files from different branches
3. Also compare 2 files in your local repo.

I do understand that all of the problems are solvable if I had a good understanding of the git commands and theory. I need something to simplify my suffering for now:)

Comment: None of that needs to be done in your text editor. Grab a graphical Git client and make sure you get the training you need.

Comment: You can ask on reddit for such plugin recommendation questions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Neogit or vim-fugitive
but I prefer using lazygit outside of vim

Comment: thanks a lot, I found that lunar-vim has integrated lazygit, you can open with leader+g+g

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting plugin is [`diffview.nvim`](https://github.com/sindrets/diffview.nvim) which adds the `:DiffviewFileHistory` command which shows you all the changes of a file (and branch). As explained by the maintainer [here](https://github.com/sindrets/diffview.nvim/issues/95#issuecomment-995945591) you can use `:DiffviewFileHistory --base=LOCAL %` (`%` means the current file) to open up the the current file on the one side of the panel while the other panel holds the code of the other commits.